# JFileChooser filtering files by name as you type

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, filter, jfilechooser

I have figured out how to filter by file-type, but I cannot figure out how to filter out files as I type on my keyboard in the file-name textfield. If I have 1000 files in my directory and two of them start with the letter *q* then I expect that when I type the word *q* in my `JFileChooser` it will filter out all files that do not start with *q* and this should continue as I type and the best possible match should be selected. Is there no exemplar for this? It seems like every `JFileChooser` question and tutorial out there is only concerned with filtering by file-type and not by name.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075004/core-java/speed-up-file-searching-in-jfilechooser.html)?

Comment: That article is from 2001 and claims that in 1.4 the JFileChooser has a built-in type-ahead selector. I have not been able to find this. I have multiple issues with the article too. First, the "findJList" method is hackish. Second, there is no complete code example. Third and last, the behavior for filtering out files from view while you type is not addressed. There has to be a more elegant way of implementing this behavior in modern Java.

Comment: Are you aware that if you select a file and type a sequence of letters it navigate for you to the files starting with that sequence?

Comment: The text field you want to modify is a `private` field inside `MetalFileChooserUI` (assuming Metal LAF). You don't have many options here - copy paste code from the UI class or iterate through the file chooser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (for Metal LAF). Although it is a terrible solution in itself, the other options are not more appetizing.

```
public class FilterChooser {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    JTextField tf = (JTextField) ((JPanel) ((JPanel) chooser.getComponent(3)).getComponent(0)).getComponent(1);

    FilterChooser() {

        tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                modifyFilter();
            }

            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                modifyFilter();
            }

            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

                modifyFilter();
            }
        });

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(f);

        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    void modifyFilter() {

        final String text = tf.getText();
        chooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File f) {

                return (f.isDirectory() || f.getName().startsWith(text));
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new FilterChooser();
    }
}
```

Notes and explanations:

- The text field in a JFileChooser is declared in the `MetalFileChooserUI` class as a `private` field, hence no easy way to reach it. I fetch it into `tf` the way I do because I did my homework and checked where it is located - if the layout changes (won't happen in the next many years due to backwards compatibility) this *will* break. You can alternatively recursively iterate through child components.
- I set the filter for files only. If you want this to apply to directories, change the `accept` method of the `FileFilter`.
- The filter is case-sensitive as it is currently implemented. You can modify this behavior by changing the `accept` method of the `FileFilter`.
- I added the empty frame just so the JVM will exit when you close it (the file chooser, being a dialog, does not do this).
- Depending on the bigger picture, set the modifiers of the fields and methods to your needs.

Comment: This works! I have one problem though, if I click on a file, then click away from it on a directory and then click on that file again the selection in the fileChooser disappears. I am stumped as to why this is happening...

Comment: Hmmm... yes. It happens also the first time you select a file. What happens is that whenever the filter is changed, the files and folders list is refreshed and you lost the current selection. It actually happens as you type also, but you can't notice it in this case. It might be possible to make it that selecting a file doesn't put its name into the field automatically if you want.

Comment: Iv'e tried to reselect the file after setting the new filter and the list refreshes, but it's not that easy. For some reason `invokeLater` fails to do the job here. There are desperate measure that can be taken, what do think?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that implementing a full-scale auto-complete for a `JFileChooser` might not be trivial.  You would need access to the JTextField of the chooser, but that isn't readily available (though not impossible).  You could then apply a custom DocumentFilter to that field, and then auto-populate (and partial select the back end of the word) as the user types.

Further reading:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter

However, that seems like a lot of work.

Instead, are you aware that JFileChooser allows you to create a filter on-the-fly? Just bring up the chooser, type in `'q*'`, hit ENTER, and the chooser will show only the files that begin with 'q'.

Comment: The behavior you just described with the * works great. I would like to make that behavior occur for every keystroke and not be limited to adding a * and hitting enter. Is that possible? I am not interested in a full scale auto-complete. I want to filter as I type.

Comment: `I am not interested in a full scale auto-complete. I want to filter as I type.`  I don't see the difference.  Could you explain?

Comment: I want to filter as I type. == autocomplete for me, but these features by default uses startWith, not contains, couldn't be, I'm think there no issue with, but as is described @splungebob not easy and to required the effort

Comment: By filter as I type I mean that if I hit "f" in the JTextField below, then all the files in the JList above should be gone unless they start with "f". I do not expect the JTextField to auto-complete to the first file that start with "f", which is auto-completion. Does that make what I mean clear?

Answer (score 0):

I have the behavior that I want now. I still cannot believe what a struggle this was, but I guess nobody in the Swing community ever saw it fit to have the JFileChooser have this behavior or have better hooks for implementing it. Thank you user1803551 for your answer, I am accepting your answer and I posted mine just to show how I tweaked yours to get my exact desired behavior.

```
public void setupListeners()
{
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    JTextField fileChooserTextField = (JTextField) ((JPanel) ((JPanel) chooser.getComponent(3)).getComponent(0)).getComponent(1);

    chooser.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
    {
       @Override
       public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
       {
       }
       @Override
       public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
       {
          filterAsYouType(fileChooserTextField, chooser);
       }
       @Override
       public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
       {
       }
    });
}

    private void filterAsYouType(final JTextField tf, final JFileChooser chooser)
    {
    final String text = tf.getText();
    chooser.setFileFilter(new FileFilter()
    {
       @Override
       public boolean accept(File f)
       {
          if(text.equals("")
          {
             return true;
          }
          if(f.getName().equals(text))
          {
             chooser.setSelectedFile(f);
             tf.setCaretPosition(text.length());
          }
          if(f.getName().startsWith(text))
          {
             return true;
          }
          return false;
       }
       @Override
       public String getDescription()
       {
          return null;
       }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're implementing only 1 method in `KeyListener`, you better use a `KeyAdapter`. Also, not sure why you need to check text equals to "", empty string works automatically; you're missing a `return true` in the second `if`.

Comment: Also, I believe that the KeyListener needs to be added to the JTextField, not the Chooser